# React.js / Redux: Functional Components, legacy state/props and do I have to connect every component that uses the store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, components, react-props

some questions about React.js and Redux:

1. Can functional components also take advantage of the store and the states saved therein? e.g maybe in combination with React hooks like `useEffect()`?
2. In general, I can combine multiple reducers to one rootReducer and `createStore(rootReducer)` with it, and then pass it to a Provider Component that wraps my  Component with it, this way, the store should be globally available in my whole app, correct?
3. For every component that want to use the store / states, do I always have to import the 2 methods `mapStateToProps()` and `mapDispatchToProps()` from react-redux for every Component and then connect them? Or can I also do this on some top-level component and make the usage of redux available in all my components globally, like in question 2) with the store provider?
4. last question: Can I still use the `this.state` property in my Components or use them in parallel as an addition (e.g for this Component isolated states) and then get the props from this state as usual with `this.state.someState` or is this not possible anymore when I already use Redux? And in the same way, can I still use / pass props to my components and read them from my Components as well, or is everything managed by state now only? (Or has the passing of props to my children nothing to do with Redux)?

Comment: I think I've answered all your questions below. Let me know if you have any additional thoughts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes functional components can take advantage of the store. Its arguably much cleaner to read since props can be destructured right away.

```
const MyComponent = ({ auth }) => {
    const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
       if(auth.user){
          setDisplay(true)
       }
    }, [auth.user])    


    return(
       <div>
          { display ? "Content": "Please sign in" }
       </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return{
      auth: state.auth
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

2) That is correct. You can also use `combineReducers()` which in some ways is cleaner to read.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux"
import authReducer from "./reducers/authReducer"
import postReducer from "./reducers/postReducer"

const store = createStore(combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    post: postReducer
}))

export default store
```

Then import store, wrap your App.js in a Provider and give it a prop of that store.

3) Generally, if you want your component to have direct access to the store it is a recognized pattern to use `connect()` in each one. Whether you decide to use `mapStateToProps()` or `mapDispatchToProps()` is entirely dependent on what that component needs to do. It does not required that you use both, you can just define one or the other in the `connect()`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { addPost } from "/actions/postActions"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

const Form = ({ addPost }) => {
   const [text, setText] = useState("")

   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      addPost(text)
   }

   return(
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}/>
     </form>
   )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
     addPost: (text) => dispatch(addPost(text))
   }
}


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Form)
```

4) You might have noticed by now that in the context of components, `redux-state` is stored as `props`. They are entirely different and isolated streams of data. So `state` remains untouched and controlled by the component itself. You can still freely use methods like `this.state.dog` even when your component is connected to the store. This is the isolation between `component-state` and `redux-state`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

class MyDogs extends React.Component{
   state = {
     dog: "Tucker"
   }

   render(){
     return(
       <div>
          Component State Value: {this.state.dog} //Tucker
          Redux State Value: {this.props.dog} //Buddy
       </div>
   )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return { 
      dog: state.dog
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyDogs)
```

Comment: You're welcome! I hope this helps prepare you for your next React-Redux app :) @user2774480

Comment: for sure it will! ;)